# adding a heading to a section that uses display:table and display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of difficulty in displaying a table. I use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` a lot for sections usually. Especially when I just want to center the content of a section vertically. So to say, I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="red">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following css applied to the html:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.red {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Now there is a small problem. I want to add a section header to this particular section and the section header has to be a child of `.wrapper`, so the HTML changes as below :

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="section-heading">
    <h1>section heading</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="cell">
    <div class="red">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now the problem with using display table and table-cell is that when I add a header to the section, I can't add it without it affecting the other child elements of `.wrapper` . So how do I add a heading (when the heading is added in the above HTML the `.cell` div seems to be moving horizontally slightly)?

Of course I could use absolute positioning, but I was just wondering, is there something that can be done, without taking the heading element out of the flow?

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7xo353hg/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding display:table-row to the section-heading?

```
.wrapper > .section-heading{
    display:table-row;
    height:auto;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7xo353hg/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can make heading container `display: table-row`:

```
.section-heading {
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check the demo:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper * {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.red {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.section-heading {
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section-heading">
        <h1>section heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but see how `.cell` , is no more at the center of `.wrapper` , which is exactly what i want , i think your demo is the closest i can get , so i might have to go with position absolute itself as having `cell` at the vertical center of `wrapper` is my main objective . Thanks though !

Comment: I meant `.red` not `.cell`

Comment: Actually gopalraju spotted this: you need to add `height:auto;` also.

Comment: Another approach is to use `position: absolute` for heading, but without `top` and `left` values: http://jsfiddle.net/7xo353hg/5/

Comment: and what does height:auto do ?

Comment: height auto prevents heading cell from taking to much vertical space.

Comment: ohh yes Thanks ! , i'll accepts gopalrajus answer though as he answered 1st , i'd give you +1 though , wish i could give you more :D

Comment: No problem, although technically I answered first (12 seconds earlier), cheers :D